# Could not access bean in action Struts2

Tags: struts2

I have index.jsp where I have one link,on clicking on that link that page specific action gets called.Now as on the click of this link,I  need to display a page with already populated multiselect list along with few input text fields,in the constructor of the action I populated the `TransactionBean` which will be bound with fields on next page i.e transactionData.jsp.

The transactionData.jsp page is getting displayed correctly with populated multiselected list.Now user can select values from multiselect list and can enter dates in text field and will click on click button,so that a bar chart is displayed.

On click on Click button ,I am calling another action ,which also has TransactionBean as its property.In the execute method of this action, I am trying to access transactionbean with its getter but it gives me `NullPointerException`. I got to know that, if we are submitting a page which has fields of bean binded ,then on calling action,bean will be instantiated automatically through interceptors but seems like something is not correct here.

index.jsp

```xml
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>

        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <s:form action="displayAction.action">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <a href="<s:url action="displayAction.action"/>">Transaction Chart</a>
    </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

DisplayAction.java

```java
package com.tutorialspoint.struts2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class DisplayAction extends ActionSupport {

    TransactionBean transactionBean;

    public TransactionBean getTransactionBean() {
        return transactionBean;
    }

    public void setTransactionBean(TransactionBean transactionBean) {
        this.transactionBean = transactionBean;
    }

    public String execute() {
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public DisplayAction() {
        System.out.println("Inside Constructor");
        List<String> leftChannelsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        leftChannelsList.add("Channel1");
        leftChannelsList.add("Channel2");
                //TransactionBean transactionBean  = new TransactionBean();

        setTransactionBean(new TransactionBean());
        getTransactionBean().setLeftChannelsList(leftChannelsList);

        //Transaction Type Dta
        List<String> leftTransTypesList = new ArrayList<String>();
        leftTransTypesList.add("TransType1");
        leftTransTypesList.add("TransType2");
        getTransactionBean().setLeftTransTypesList(leftTransTypesList);

    }
}
```

transactionData.jsp

```xml
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <s:head theme="ajax" debug="true"/>
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
<body bgcolor="grey">

<s:form action="displayChart.action">

    <s:datetimepicker label="Select From" name="transactionBean.fromDate" displayFormat="MM-dd-yy" required="true" />  <s:datetimepicker label="Select To" name="transactionBean.toDate" displayFormat="MM-dd-yy" required="true" />

    <s:optiontransferselect
        label="Channels"
        name="transactionBean.leftChannels"
        leftTitle="Unselected Channels"
        rightTitle="Selected Channels"
        list="transactionBean.leftChannelsList"
        multiple="true"
        headerKey="-1"
        doubleList="transactionBean.rightChannelsList"
        doubleName="transactionBean.rightChannels"
        doubleHeaderKey="-1"
        doubleHeaderValue="Please Select"/>

    <!-- Transaction Types -->

    <s:optiontransferselect

        label="transaction Types"
        name="transactionBean.leftTransTypes"
        leftTitle="Unselected Transaction Type"
        rightTitle="Selected Transaction Type"
        list="transactionBean.leftTransTypesList"
        multiple="true"
        headerKey="-1"
        doubleList="transactionBean.rightTransTypesList"
        doubleName="transactionBean.rightTransTypes"
        doubleHeaderKey="-1"
        doubleHeaderValue="Please Select"/>

    <s:submit value="click" align="center"/>
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

JfreeChartAction.java

```java
public class JfreeChartAction extends ActionSupport {

    private JFreeChart chart;

    private TransactionBean transactionBean;
    private TransactionDao transactionDao;

    public TransactionDao getTransactionDao() {
        return transactionDao;
    }

    public void setTransactionDao(TransactionDao transactionDao) {
        this.transactionDao = transactionDao;
    }

    public TransactionBean getTransactionBean() {
        return transactionBean;
    }

    public void setTransactionBean(TransactionBean transactionBean) {
        this.transactionBean = transactionBean;
    }

    // This method will get called if we specify <param name="value">chart</param>
    public JFreeChart getChart() {
        return chart;
    }

    public void setChart(JFreeChart chart) {
        this.chart = chart;
    }

    public JfreeChartAction() {}

    public String execute() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Inside Execute: Start");

        System.out.println("From date:" + getTransactionBean().getFromDate());
        System.out.println("From date:" + getTransactionBean().getToDate());
        System.out.println("leftChannelsList:" + getTransactionBean().getLeftChannelsList());
        System.out.println("Left Trans type List" + getTransactionBean().getLeftTransTypesList());

        DefaultCategoryDataset dataSet = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        dataSet.setValue(0, "01-04-2014", "Channel1");
        dataSet.setValue(15000, "01-04-2014", "Channel2");

        dataSet.setValue(9000, "01-05-2014", "Channel1");
        dataSet.setValue(1500, "01-05-2014", "Channel2");

        dataSet.setValue(10000, "01-06-2014", "Channel1");
        dataSet.setValue(8000, "01-06-2014", "Channel2");

        chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(
                "Demo Bar Chart", //Chart title
                "Mobile Manufacturer", //Domain axis label
                "TRANSACTIONS", //Range axis label
                dataSet, //Chart Data
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // orientation
                true, // include legend?
                true, // include tooltips?
                false // include URLs?
        );

        chart.setBorderVisible(true);
        System.out.println("Inside Execute: End");

        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Struts.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>

    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="displayAction"
                class="com.tutorialspoint.struts2.DisplayAction"
                method="execute">
            <result name="success">transactionsData.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>

    <package name="defaultJfreeChart" namespace="/" extends="jfreechart-default">
        <action name="displayChart"
                class="com.tutorialspoint.struts2.JfreeChartAction"
                method="execute">

            <result name="success" type="chart">
                <param name="value">chart</param>
                <param name="type">jpeg</param>
                <param name="width">600</param>
                <param name="height">400</param>
            </result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

TransactionBean.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;

public class TransactionBean {

    private Date dateTime;
    private Integer volume;
    private String leftChannels;
    private String rightChannels;
    private String toDate;
    private String fromDate;
    private List<String> leftChannelsList;
    private List<String> rightChannelsList;

    //Transaction type data 
    private String leftTransTypes;
    private List<String> leftTransTypesList;
    private String rightTransTypes;
    private List<String> rightTransTypesList;



    public Date getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }

    public void setDateTime(Date dateTime) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }

    public Integer getVolume() {
        return volume;
    }

    public void setVolume(Integer volume) {
        this.volume = volume;
    }

        public TransactionBean(){
        //System.out.println("Inside TransactionBean constructor");
        }

    public String getLeftTransTypes() {
        return leftTransTypes;
    }

    public void setLeftTransTypes(String leftTransTypes) {
        this.leftTransTypes = leftTransTypes;
    }

    public List<String> getLeftTransTypesList() {
        return leftTransTypesList;
    }

    public void setLeftTransTypesList(List<String> leftTransTypesList) {
        this.leftTransTypesList = leftTransTypesList;
    }

    public String getRightTransTypes() {
        return rightTransTypes;
    }

    public void setRightTransTypes(String rightTransTypes) {
        this.rightTransTypes = rightTransTypes;
    }

    public List<String> getRightTransTypesList() {
        return rightTransTypesList;
    }

    public void setRightTransTypesList(List<String> rightTransTypesList) {
        this.rightTransTypesList = rightTransTypesList;
    }


    public String getToDate() {
        return toDate;
    }

    public void setToDate(String toDate) {
        this.toDate = toDate;
    }

    public String getFromDate() {
        return fromDate;
    }

    public void setFromDate(String fromDate) {
        this.fromDate = fromDate;
    }

    public String getLeftChannels() {
        return leftChannels;
    }

    public void setLeftChannels(String leftChannels) {
        this.leftChannels = leftChannels;
    }

    public String getRightChannels() {
        return rightChannels;
    }

    public void setRightChannels(String rightChannels) {
        this.rightChannels = rightChannels;
    }

    public List<String> getRightChannelsList() {
        return rightChannelsList;
    }

    public void setRightChannelsList(List<String> rightChannelsList) {

        this.rightChannelsList = rightChannelsList;
    }

    public List<String> getLeftChannelsList() {
        return leftChannelsList;
    }

    public void setLeftChannelsList(List<String> leftChannelsList) {

        this.leftChannelsList = leftChannelsList;
    }

}
```

Comment: Post the code for your bean.

Comment: Hi Roman,Thanks for your reply. I have added TransactionBean in above code.

Comment: What version of Struts are you using?

Comment: Struts2-core-2.0.8.jar,struts2-jFreechart-pligin-2.0.11.1.jar,struts2-spring-plugin-2.0.11.1.jar,xwork-2.0.4.jar

Comment: This version is too old and doesn't allow to do what you want.

Comment: can you please let me know which version should be used.

Answer (score 0):

> can you please let me know which version should be used.

Always use the [latest version](https://struts.apache.org/announce.html#a20140503). At the moment it's Struts 2.3.16.3 GA. You can also see [Version Notes](https://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/version-notes-23163.html) and [Migration Guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Migration+Guide).