# Action class is not getting invoked after upgrading Struts to 2.3.37

Tags: struts2

I have  configured in my index.html page that calls Action servlet. Initially the Struts version was 2.0.14 and it was working fine when the web.xml has the below filter mapping

struts2
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher

```
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
<url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
```

My struts.xml looks like

```
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />

    <include file="utils.xml"/>
    
</struts>
```

After I upgraded the struts version to 2.3.37, I have modified the web.xml filter mapping to

```
 <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

and when I click the href, I'm getting HTTP error 404 saying could not find action class even though my action classes are defined in struts.xml. Please advise.

Comment: What is the cause of 404 error? Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25738629/573032) answer.

Comment: There is no information here anybody could use to help.

Comment: Added more details.

Comment: Turn on debugging mode and post error stacktrace.